# Can't resolve 'url' in redux-auth-wrapper

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I used the command npm start to active my ReactJS project and got this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/redux-auth-wrapper/history4/locationHelper.js 17:11-25

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\web_test\node_modules\redux-auth-wrapper\history4'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

I tried to use npm install to reinstall node_modules again and got another errors

```
npm WARN @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.6 requires a peer of ajv@>=8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@5.0.1 requires a peer of @popperjs/core@^2.9.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.   
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table2-filter@1.3.3 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-bootstrap-table2-filter@1.3.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 1569 packages in 7.025s

228 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details        

found 3 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

What should I do to fix it. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install **url** with `yarn add url -D`, that solved the problem.